# Exclude first line of error stack in Node? / Custom Error Type in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there any way to create an`Error` object using a JavaScript factory without including the line from the factory in the stack?

For example, this:

```
if (!member) {
   return next(errs.init('Invalid email address.', errs.UNAUTHORIZED));
}
```

... produces this:

```
Error: Invalid email address.
    at Object.init (/.../bin/utils/errors.util.js:21:16)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/.../routes/auth/auth.routes.js:37:30)
    at /.../node_modules/kareem/index.js:177:19
    at /.../node_modules/kareem/index.js:109:16
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:419:9)
```

The first line of the stack is actually a line from within the factory.  The actual problem starts on the second line of the stack.

I'm using WebStorm and the console window ever only shows the first line of the stack.  You must scroll to get to the additional lines.

Comment: Capture the error before it is thrown and just remove the offending part of the error message string? This seems like more trouble than it's worth - you don't want to be changing production code just so that it looks nice in your IDE.

Comment: Never said I wanted to alter it.  Just looking for a technique to show where the actual error exists instead of the factory.

Comment: What's the value of the factory here? `throw new Error('derp')` seems quick enough.

Comment: @JoeAttardi Not when you want to add extra stuff to the Error (status code, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to get it to work in Node by overriding the context in a custom error:

```
function ApiError (message, status, context) {

    this.name = 'ApiError';

    this.message = message || '';
    this.status  = status || 500;

    Error.captureStackTrace(this, ( context || ApiError ));
}
require('util').inherits(ApiError, Error);

function init (message, status) {
    return (new ApiError(message, status, init));
}

module.exports = {

    init            : init,
    ApiError        : ApiError,

    BAD_REQUEST     : 400,
    UNAUTHORIZED    : 401,
    FORBIDDEN       : 403,
    NOT_FOUND       : 404,
    CONFLICT        : 409
};
```

This allows either:

```
return next(errs.init('Invalid email address.', errs.UNAUTHORIZED));
```

... or ...

```
return next(new errs.ApiError('Invalid email address.', errs.UNAUTHORIZED));
```